# How realistic is it really to transition from an applied maths PhD to a career in finance?

Tags: phd, mathematics, career-path, finance

I am currently in my final year of PhD in mathematics (functional analysis of PDEs) at one of the top 3 universities in Japan. I earnt my master's (mathematics) here too, and a bachelor's (theoretical physics & mathematics) in a decent university in Ireland. My grades are all almost perfect.

I have a few options for postdoc lined up, but have decided I would rather a career that has a higher salary and is more intellectually stimulating than what I'm currently doing. Ideally, I would have liked a quantitative trader/analyst role, and was assured by some friends with those jobs or similar that people with maths degrees were in high demand for these roles.

Well, I have been applying to many of these roles (in particular **graduate programmes**) and similar in Ireland, the UK, and Japan for about a month now and have been met only with rejections. I'm sure one obvious response here is just to not give up yet, but after receiving such a large volume of rejections I think I need to get some second opinions on how realistic my expectations are.

Has anyone here any similar experience to my own? Anyone have any interesting sources with data/examples of people making the same sort of transition I am? Are there any actions I could reasonably take in the next 6 months or so to boost my CV significantly?

Other than my experience and skills in pure maths, teaching, and presentations that obviously come from my academia experience, I do have experience with numerical solutions (which I of course mark as 'programming' on my CV) with Python and MATLAB. I've also starting reading textbooks and taking some courses on Coursera for financial mathematics.

Comment: What did you try to learn about finance? Why should they pick you and pay for your formation instead of a Economics graduate with some analytical skills?
Numerical solutions should not count as programming: in the finance world if they want a programmer they look for a programmer. Try to be more specific, but not too specific. Did you try to use the risk-analysis tools that are nowadays used?